# Does the M2 chip support Third Level Address Translation (EL3 TTBR0_EL3)?

Tags: apple-silicon

I am trying to understand if the new M2 Macs support Third Level Address Translation (TTBR0_EL3) which in the ARM world is called Stage 3 Translation in the ARM specification?

Comment: Just to confirm what you're asking about... SLAT is usually "second level address translation", which the M2 supports. Or are you asking about the existence of TTBR0_EL3?

Comment: Yes you are right. Sorry I am new to this and are confusing the terms

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the M2 Macs do have TTBR0_EL3 and support this type of address translation.

I assume you mean TLAT in the context of the secure monitor, and not in terms of nested layers of virtualisation.

Comment: Actually, I am not aware of the difference, could you elaborate on this?

Comment: Hmm, can you explain the context of your question? - Why is it you want to ask the question? We might be talking about two entirely different things here.

Comment: That has been asked @jksoegaard - https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/466761/5472

Comment: @bmike Actually that question is about something entirely different - it is about nested virtualization. This question is about stage 3 memory address translation in EL3. Hardware assisted virtualisation software such as hypervisors run in EL2 - and they make use of what is known as stage 2 memory address translation. MAT is not the main component of hardware assisted virtualization.